# Flutter with firebase_messaging - how to custom message on permission dialog?

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I'm using fcm and firebase_messaging to send push notification to flutter app, and want to custom permission message when executing FirebaseMessaging().requestNotificationPermissions for ios remote notification.

Now I have permission dialog below

[image: Current permission dialog screenshot]

How to custom '"" Would Like to Send You Notifications', 'Notifications may include alerts, sounds, and icon...', and 'Don't Allow/Allow'? Does anyone any idea?

and my code

```
final FirebaseMessaging  _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
await _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
              const IosNotificationSettings(
                sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
await _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((settings) {
              debugPrint('Settings registered: $settings');
          });
```

Here's my `flutter doctor -v` result

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.1 19B88, locale ja-JP)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at /usr/local/bin/flutter
    • Framework revision 27321ebbad (6 weeks ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/shunmanabe/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.3.1, Build version 11C504
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.41.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.7.1

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 11 • 4B5E0CE0-8D25-49CC-BEBA-0BDE35991977 • ios •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-3 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might help: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/211309/216320

Answer (score 12, accepted):

first update to the latest firebase messaging dependency in your pubspec.yaml file

```
firebase_messaging: ^9.1.0
```

then create an instance of firebase messaging

```
final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
```

then request for the permission

```
Future initialize(context) async {
if (Platform.isIOS) {
  firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  );
}
```

}

Comment: What about Android?

Comment: @YashV.Monpara `Android applications are not required to request permission.` https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/

Answer (score 6):

In my case i updated the firebase dependency firebase_messaging: ^10.0.2 and replace

```
_fcm.requestNotificationPermissions(const IosNotificationSettings())
```

to

```
 _fcm.requestPermission(
        alert: true,
        announcement: false,
        badge: true,
        carPlay: false,
        criticalAlert: false,
        provisional: false,
        sound: true,
      );
```

but we will have to change

```
_fcm.configure()
```

as well, change it with below code.

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
RemoteNotification _notification = message.notification;
AndroidNotification _android = message.notification?.android;
});
```

and problem solved.